# Pass data from Firebase to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, firebase

I've been stumped on this for days so I figured it was time to seek some advice. I am building an application that uses Firebase for authentication purposes and stores user videos in MySQL database. Firebase returns an object that includes a unique ID. The goal is to save the UID along with video that the user uploads so that the vids can be easily filtered by user. Initially I attempted something like this:

```
if(authData){ //this is provided by Firebase
var current_user = authData.uid;
$.ajax({      //I fire the UID from Firebase to user.php
        type: "post",
        url: "user.php",
        data: {
            user: current_user
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then in user.php:

```
<?php

$userid = $_POST['user'];


?>
```

I can echo $userid and verify that it is being passed to user.php just fine, but the dilemma is that I want to be able to include $userid in viduploader.php which looks something like this:

```
<?php  
require 'conn.php';
include 'user.php';

$target = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

mysqli_select_db($connector, "uservideos");

if (!mysqli_select_db($connector, "uservideos")) {
die("Uh oh, couldn't select database");
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO uservideos (user, uservideo) VALUES ('$userid','$target')";

mysqli_query($connector, $sql)

?>
```

When I submit my form to upload a user video (viduploader.php) the $userid variable is null. I can set static variables in user.php and retrieve them with no problems, so I am assuming the issue is because I am passing the value of $userid in an ajax call that is obviously taking place after the .php files have all been initialized and so the when I include user.php in viduploader.php the value of $userid has not yet been set. Any thoughts on how I can best achieve my goal of making this Firebase variable that is provided when a user is logged-in available to my PHP? Thanks in advance!

Comment: call viduploader.php file in ajax, than include user.php file after getting variable.

Answer (score 0):

From ajax you are calling `user.php` but you are trying to fetch your `userid` variable form `viduploader.php`. The ajax data is not exist there because you have called `user.php` not `viduploader.php`. So, you can just trying by calling `viduploader.php` form ajax instead of `user.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using session or cookies. Set the $userid to session or cookies and use it anywhere in your project. you can find more about PHP session [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) and about cookies [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

OR you can simply make an ajax call to viduploader.php

Comment: I've tried making the ajax call to viduploader.php in order to initialize $userid, but it still does not work. PHP session looks promising so I'm going to give that a try. Thanks!